# Python find a specific word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find if a string matches the word 'for'

```
str = 'foreign'
re.findall(r'for', str)
```

the above code outputs ['for'], but that's not what i'm looking for.
Perhaps I must use re.match, but I am not sure. 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to find if the word `for` is in a larger text, or if the *whole* string is equal to `for`? And why not use `str == 'for'` if the latter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\b` to mark the border of some word:

```
In [782]: s = 'foreign, for fore'

In [783]: re.findall(r'\bfor\b', s)
Out[783]: ['for']
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters):

> \b is an assertion that the current position is located at a word boundary

Comment: But he says that's not the output he is looking for.

Comment: @Joseph so what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I need to scan if a string is the keyword 'for'.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to check if the string contains the word or part of it?
the pythonic way to do it is:

```
In [15]: s = 'foreign, for fore'

In [16]: 'for' in s
Out[16]: True
```

Comment: that's something he's unclear about does he wants to make sure the entire word as a word is contained in the sentence or not.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a boolean? How about `bool(re.findall(r'for', str))`? (By the way, an `if` statement would do that implicitely, so `if re.findall(r'for', str):` is ok).

If you don't need to use a regexp, you can also use: `'for' in str` (which “returns” a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `regex` to check if a substring is in a string, try:

```
>>> import re
# If input is a sentence
>>> s = "foreign"
>>> substr = r"for"
>>> [i for i in s.split() if re.findall(substr,i)]
['foreign']

>>> s = "forex is a foreign concept ."
>>> [i for i in s.split() if re.findall(substr,i)]
['forex', 'foreign']

# If input is a list of words
>>> s = ['forex', 'is', 'a', 'foreign', 'concept', '.']
>>> [i for i in s if re.findall(substr,i)]
['forex', 'foreign']
```

If you want to check the existence of a substring in a string and return the string:

```
>>> s = "foreign"
>>> substr = "for"
>>> [i for i in s.split() if substr in s]
['foreign']
```

If you want to check the existence of a substring in a string and return a boolean:

```
>>> s = "foreign"
>>> substr = "for"
>>> substr in s
True
>>> "for" in "foreign"
True
```

Of course, trying to ask python in natural language is wont work:

```
>>> "for" in "foreign"
True
>>> is "for" in "foreign" ?
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    is "for" in "foreign" ?
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```